# How to load fixtures inside Entity with 2 foreign keys?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

i have 3 Entities: Licence, Responsable and Specialite.
the responsable can manage many Licences and Specialite can have many Licences.
I created already fixtures for Responsable and Specialite.
However, i tried the following code to load fixture inside Licence, but it is not working ? any help ?

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Licence;
use App\Entity\Responsable;
use App\Entity\Specialite;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LicenceFixtures extends Fixture
{

private $specialites;

private $responsables;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->specialites = $em->getRepository(Specialite::class);

    $this->responsables = $em->getRepository(Responsable::class);

}
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{



    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

    $specialite = $this->specialites->find($i+9);

    $resp = $this->responsables->find($i+1);

        $licence = new Licence();
        $licence->setTitre('licence '.$i);
        $licence->setCode('code'.$i);
        $licence->setEtablissement('etabli'.$i);
        $licence->setDateOuverture('2018/2019');
        $licence->setSpecialite($specialite);
        $licence->setResponsable($resp);
        $manager->persist($licence);


    }

    $manager->flush();

}
}
```

Comment: Have you try to use objects references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify [loading order](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order) to explain doctrine the correct order, so it will load all Responsable and Specialite first

```
  public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            SpecialityFixtures::class,
            ResponsablesFixtures::class,
        );
    }
```

Then, use `AbstractFixture` `setReference` and `addReference` methods to correctly [share entities](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).

In `SpecialityFixtures` you can do like so:

```
$speciality = new Speciality();    
$this->addReference('some.name', $speciality);
$this->em->persist($speciality);
```

And in `LicenceFixtures`:

```
   $licence->setSpecialite($this->getReference('some.name'));
```

Comment: your code looks fine, you just need to extend it a bit

Comment: should i keep everything and add the method getDependencies() and also addReference() in SpecialityFixtures ?

Comment: yes, but the most important is fixtures order, follow the documentation I provided via links

Comment: thanks for your time, but should addReference be implemented inside the loop after persist() ?

Comment: yes, that's possible, you can figure out some specific name, depending on id, for example `speciality.1` and use it in the loop, this way is better than using repositories, this is how you can keep data synchronized in an obvious was

Comment: loading order  and share entities. are 2 differents things, can i use just one of them ?

Comment: loading order is the one that should fix your problem, share entities approach implementation is not required but recommended